# Change css class for the first 3 records extracted from mysql

Tags: php, html, css

I have a query that extracts the product categories and lists them in a div. 
Now I would like to add a margin-bottom to the css class of the **first 3 records** extracts.

css

```
.icons-box {padding: 20px 10px 10px 10px;}
```

php:

```
 $cat_list = "SELECT *
              FROM tbl_category
              WHERE cat_parent_id >0 ORDER BY cat_id ASC";
                 $result_list = dbQuery($cat_list);
                   while($row_list = dbFetchAssoc($result_list)) { 
                     extract($row_list);
?>
<div class="icons-box">
 <h3><?php echo $cat_name; ?></h3>
 <p><?php echo $cat_description; ?></p>
</div> 
<?php } ?>
```

how can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If i understand your code correctly, you could add something like the below into your CSS:

```
.icons-box p:nth-child(-n+3) {
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

[More on `nth-child` from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child)

> The :nth-child(an+b) CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has
>   an+b-1 siblings before it in the document tree, for a given positive
>   or zero value for n, and has a parent element.
>
> This can more clearly be described this way: the matching element is
>   the bth child of an element after all its children have been split
>   into groups of a elements each.
>
> The values a and b must both be integers, and the index of an
>   element's first child is 1.
>
> In other words, this class matches all children whose index fall in
>   the set { an + b; n = 0, 1, 2, ... }.
>
> Among other things, this allows selectors to match every other row in
>   a table.

Comment: I tried to add that class but does not work
.icons-box p:nth-child(-n+3) {
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

Comment: You HTML may be different from what I expected, try `.icons-box:nth-child(-n+3) { margin-bottom:20px; }`

Comment: In this way, the rule is applied to the entire while loop and not just the first 3 records